# Joblib Parallel seems to crash without an explicit error message

Tags: python, joblib

I am running a script that computes the Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrix (GLCM) (as implemented in Scikit-image) and the greycoprops (Scikit-image implementation, contrast, energy, and correlation) over a series of large images. The GLCM and its properties are computed over subregions (sliding window) of the larger images until the whole extension of the image is covered. The results are stored in arrays with the same dimensions as the input images, after this, the values of the arrays (greycoprops) are averaged in the horizontal direction and stored together in a new array.

I order to increase the computation performance of the code, I used the Joblib library and its function "Parallel". By using this function multiple images are evaluated at the same time. The code runs fine for up to 9 image arrays with dimensions of 25600 x 512 pixels down to 6400 x 128 pixels at the same time. However, I tried to run the code simultaneously on 3 image arrays with the following dimensions: 67242 x 512, 33621 x 256, and 16810 x 128 pixels without success. The script seems to crash without any error message on the command window. I observed from the information provided in the Windows Task Manager that I am reaching the maximum memory of my desktop computer. I am not sure if this is related to the problem that I am experiencing with my script.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions to fix my script?